# Zurb Foundation for Apps - Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args' after npm start

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

I just started testing out Foundation for Apps but haven't been able to get going yet. I am getting this error after running `npm start` in my application directory. I was following the directions on the [zurb site](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html) to get to this point

```
[11:54:09] Using gulpfile C:\Development\Experiments\foundation-test\testApp\gul
pfile.js
[11:54:09] Starting 'build'...
[11:54:09] Starting 'clean'...
[11:54:09] Finished 'clean' after 13 ms
[11:54:09] Starting 'copy'...
[11:54:09] Starting 'copy:foundation'...
[11:54:10] Finished 'copy:foundation' after 1.56 s
[11:54:10] Starting 'sass'...
[11:54:11] 'sass' errored after 788 ms
[11:54:11] Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Experiments\foundation-test\testApp\no
de_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\through2\node_m
odules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_duplex.js:20:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
[11:54:11] 'build' errored after 2.38 s
[11:54:11] Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'sass'.
[11:54:11] Finished 'copy' after 2.43 s

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! foundation-apps-template@1.1.0 start: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foundation-apps-template@1.1.0 start script 'gulp'.
```

Answer (score 0):

An update to a newer npm/node version fixed this error for me. Apparently the dependencies are handled differently.